# What is the out-of-universe reason Lucifer Morningstar's new bar called "Ex Lux"?

Tags: names, vertigo-comics, lucifer

In Neil Gaiman's *The Sandman*, Lucifer Morningstar gets tired of Hell and comes to Earth, to start a piano bar called "Lux" (best bar in Los Angeles!).

The bar has been thoroughly exploited in Mike Carey's *Lucifer* series, as his base of operation.

In the 2016 *Lucifer* comic series (written thus far by Holly Black) Lucifer returns to Earth and opens a new bar, "Ex Lux":

[image]

**What exactly is the reason for the change of name?** I thought the name was a Latin saying, but apparently ["ex lux" is not even a valid form](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/4404/1629). It has been proposed on the Latin SE thread that "Ex Lux" is suppoed to be read in English, as "former Lux", or as somewhat similar to "deluxe".

I can see both of those explanations working (the first one being more likely), but essentially it's guesswork: *Lucifer* in general is open to interpretation at least as much as all the religious texts and mythology it draws from is.

Therefore, I'll ask the following: **why exactly did Holly Black, or whoever was responsible, choose "Ex Lux" as the name for the bar?** (I'm specifically looking for commentary by the creators)

Comment: I think this is from the root, "out of". So the bar would be "Out of [the] Light"

Comment: @Valorum That's what I thought initially, but [the people from Latin SE don't think so](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/4404/1629) - "ex lux" doesn't make sense gramatically, it should be "ex lucii" in your case.

Comment: I rather suspect that the authors didn't consult Lewis & Short when they chose it. At best, they probably went to Google Translate.

Comment: @Valorum Which would be rather dissapointing, considering they had all the Internet at their disposal, while Neil Gaiman and Mike Carey went to great lengths to buy physical books to do research for their comics.

Comment: It works on a bunch of levels; it's a *former* Lux (like an ex-wife) and the name is reminiscent of Ex-Lax, a product that helps you to cleanse yourself internally, a form of chemical confession.

Comment: @Valorum Then it'd have to have the dash.

Comment: I don't want to point to the elephant in the room, but Lucifer's other name is "Lightbringer", so this could mean something like "former lighbringer"

Comment: @Gallifreyan: The only forms of "*lux*" that can follow "*ex*" are "*luce*" (singular) and "*lucibus*" (plural).  "*Ex lucii*" is just as ungrammatical as "*ex lux*", and the obvious fixed version "*ex lucio*" means "out of the pike."

Comment: I also think Latin grammar wasn't at the top of mind when naming the bar, in or out of universe. I immediately thought 'outside the light' when I read it, which is probably exactly​ the effect they wanted ( in and out of universe). It also linked back to the original name, which they probably wanted. Changing the form of the. Latin word to something that was grammatically correct but wouldn't be recognized by most people would defeat the point.

Comment: @jwodder - Yep; as in one motto used for the Miskatonic University -- **Ex Ignorantia Ad Sapientiam; Ex Luce Ad Tenebras.**  Note Ex LUCE, not Lux.  But I'm betting it this is just 'coffee table' latin; not researched, and used improperly.  Then again, in the fictional universe, HE would predate our understand of Latin, and might be using a correct form that we've forgotten.

Answer (score -3):

I can't provide sources, but I suspect it's a play on the name of the real-world laxative product "Ex-Lax", combined with "Lucifer" meaning a match, and therefore "light".

Comment: I can't think of a single reason Devil's bar would be named after a laxative.

Comment: Lucifer means a match because it was one of the devil's handles "bringer of light", not the other way around.

Comment: @TMS -- you have the etymology reversed.  Lucifer is from Lux and Fero (or several other conjugations, but all with the same meaning); combining to mean 'bearer of light', and is a very old name.  [Lucifer **matches**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Match#Friction_matches) were from the 1800s, named cleverly to integrate both the name and the fact that they smelled like Brimstone (sulfur) which was associated, in many religions, with the underworld.